# converting 'CSV' to an 'array' and then to an 'image' in Python?

Tags: python

I need to convert a csv file to an image.

[image]

I have first converted it into an array using 'np.genfromtxt' and now have to change it to an image.

How this can be done?

I have tried this code previously, it seems to give the wrong values (all the values as '255')

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code other text, copy the actual text here instead

Comment: @JamesZ Sure, from now on I will keep this in mind. It's just I am new to this.
thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#Kindly find the answer to the above question

`
import numpy as np

a=np.genfromtxt('yourfile.csv', delimiter = ',')

data = asarray([[a]])

save to npy file

arr = np.save('data.npy', data)

#load the file

data = np.load('data.npy')

print (data)

data.shape

from PIL import Image

data = data.reshape((1, 100)) #I want my data in (1,100) matrix so, I reshaped it.

im = Image.fromarray((data).astype(np.float64))

im = im.convert("L")

im.show()

im.save('s.jpg')

#To make sure what you did is correct

from PIL import Image

from numpy import asarray

load the image

image = Image.open('s.jpg')

convert image to numpy array

data = asarray(image)

print(type(data))

create Pillow image

image2 = Image.fromarray(data)

print(type(image2))

summarize image details

print(image2.size)

print (data)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is one great way to go.  The only caveat, you have to setup a lot of libraries to work with OpenCV; I had good luck using "miniconda" for this (on a Mac)

Assuming you had created a blank image, here's the code to plot text:

```
cv2.putText(image, "Hello World!", (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 255), 2)
```

I've also been enjoying the classes about OpenCV at PyImageSearch (I'm not an employee, just a student)

Comment: Thanks a ton for your suggestion. But, I have not used OpenCV, I am more comfortable in using the PIL, or NumPy libraries.
Though, Thanks again!